# can we check if App is made in phonegap or completely native

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am newbie to android and phonegap both . I just have a curiosity that can we tell by just using an app that whether it is made in phonegap or its completely native app.

Answer (score 3):

You can guess this based on the responsiveness  of the app to your interaction, but this is not a reliable waydetermine to find if app is Phonegap based or not.

Applications developed using the Phonegap will generally have a lag due to the UIWebview in iOS or its counterpart in Android. No matter how HTML's performance is tuned, due to inherent performance difference between UIWebView and native implementation of Views, the phonegap based app will be slower.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily checked if you enable layout bounds in developer options. After enabling this setting, launch your target app and observe the layout bounds highlighted. If you see container highlighted for each element of the app, its native, otherwise the app is hybrid.

Source: [See native and hybrid layout bounds appearance](https://www.techvigil.com/tips-tricks/423/differentiate-native-hybrid-app/)